# How can i simulate an user click on a web page button using Swift 2.0?

Tags: javascript, button, click, swift2, simulate

I Want to code a fake user click on a web view button to automatically load the right web page. I am working in Swift 2.0, the url doesn't contain any index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED SOLUTION: It's ugly, but works. The site requires you to jump some hoops to use it, but the `secondURL` will load a page that is just the table.

There is definitely a cleaner solution, which doesn't require JS or multiple page loads, but I leave that up to you.

I found `secondURL` by looking in Safari's Web Inspector

```
import UIKit

private let firstURL = NSURL(string: "https://legymnase67.la-vie-scolaire.fr/vsn.main/;jsessionid=E2D99A46028465A9D7F636521C64088B.node2?autolog=70caa4a471e8f6f0856735aed506b01a6307246c445beb160259f75c1c700f7978631d698cc5e0e890452bd182e5960e6153be7c4a3d2615ff0daf981a17877d46e472cdf2ef2328977c3957a58121e3556c4b9b808e22a76d0cbb994292a2144d64f367714c7dfbf4d3e24cea5f0274")!
private let secondURL = NSURL(string: "https://legymnase67.la-vie-scolaire.fr/vsn.main/releveNote/releveNotes")!

class WebController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    let webView: UIWebView = UIWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self._setupWebView()

        // load the webpage, wait 6 seconds then tap the button
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: firstURL))
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(6 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tapButton();

            // wait another 4 seconds then load the direct notes url
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: secondURL))

                // allow the page to load, and print the html
                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    print(self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.innerHTML"))
                })
            })
        })
    }

    func tapButton() {
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("changeIframeSrc(this, 'NOTES');")
    }

    func _setupWebView() {
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        let views = ["webView":webView]
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working !!:) but how can i now get the html code of the displayed page ? Because when i try, this is printing the welcome page html code

Comment: it appears that the HTML does not change between pages

Comment: Yes lt is when i Check using the developer tool in Safari

Comment: For example how can i do if i Want to get the table?

Comment: Or simply get all the html of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can inject javascript in your application web view, if you use one to display the page

If you use a UIWebView use method stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jscodestring)

If you use a WKWebView use method evaluateJavaScript(jscodestring)

Then it's a javascript problem.

- First look at element to click : document. getElementById or getElementByName, document.querySelector,  etc...
- Then use html dom method click();